# Optimize code: Return only the highest versioned filenames of a python list

Tags: python

below is a list with some file names. Each file contains the name of a 3D object and has a version number. I wrote some Python code to extract only the filenames with the highest version number of each object:

```
def list_all_objects(filenames_list):
    all_objects = [] 
    for name in filenames_list:
        object, version = split_filename(name, '_')    
        if object not in all_objects:
            all_objects.append(object)
    return all_objects 


def get_highest_version(objects_list, filenames_list): 
    all_items_all_versions = [] # list of dictionaries 
    highest_version_files = []
                      
    for item in all_objects:
        item_all_versions = dict()
        for name in filenames:
            object, version = split_filename(name, '_')
            if item in name:            
                item_all_versions[version] = name                
        all_items_all_versions.append(item_all_versions) 
                                
    for dictionary in all_items_all_versions:
        highest_version = max(dictionary.keys())
        highest_version_files.append(dictionary.get(highest_version))
                      
    return highest_version_files       
                  
        
def split_filename(name_str, separator):
    filename, ext = name_str.split('.')
    return filename.split(separator)


filenames = (
'object1_001.ext',
'object1_245.ext',
'object1_003.ext',
'object2_001.ext',
'object2_010.ext',
'object3_067.ext',
'object3_142.ext'
)

all_objects = list_all_objects(filenames) 
# print(all_objects)      
highest_version_files = get_highest_version(all_objects, filenames) 
print(highest_version_files)
```

Returns:

```
['object1_245.ext', 'object2_010.ext', 'object3_142.ext']
```

My code seems pretty convoluted to me. It would be great to see one or more examples of how to return only the highest versioned files per object in a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby()`:

```
import itertools
def get_highest_versions(filenames):
    group_key = (lambda x: x.split('_')[0].strip('object'))
    max_key = (lambda x: x.split('_')[1].split('.'))
    return [max(x[1], key=max_key) 
            for x in itertools.groupby(filenames, key=group_key)]
```

Explanation:

1. the `groupby` key will extract these digits: `object[THESE DIGITS]_123.ext` and group the filenames into buckets based on the extracted values.
2. Each bucket is then used as input to the `max` function, which uses a key that extracts these digits: `object123_[THESE DIGITS].ext`.
3. each result given by `max` is added to a list, which is then returned.

Comment: For my list above this works nicely, thank you. I should have given different object names, because most of the time their names are more like this: table_v003.ext, chair_v001.ext, lamp_v010.ext. Here the groupby key would not work, would it?

Comment: it would be easy enough to modify it a bit to make it work. It really depends on what rule you can define for the filename format, but as long as it is consistent, this same approach should he ok.

Comment: worst case, you might need to use the `re` library to extract the numeric portion. Something like `group_key = (lambda x: re.sub(r'^\w*(\d*)', r'\1', x))` and `max_key = (lambda x: re.sub(r'^.*_(\d*)', r'\1', x))` would be pretty close. I always try and avoid using a regex if the same thing can be done using the standard 'str` methods.

Comment: You forgot to sort the list before grouping. The sample input is sorted, yes, but you cant just assume that in general

Comment: @Adrian to be fair, assuming that the input *won't* be sorted is no more valid than assuming that it *will* be, given that the sample data is sorted (although `sorted()` is extremely efficient at handling pre-sorted input, so it probably doesn't hurt to include it).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run the list twice to take the objects

```
def get_object(filename):
  return filename.split("_")[0]

def get_version(filename):
  return int(filename.split("_")[1].split(".")[0])

def get_highest_version(filenames):
  fileDict = {}
  for filename in filenames:
    obj = get_object(filename)
    if (obj not in fileDict):
      fileDict[obj] = filename
    else:
      current_version = get_version(fileDict[obj])
      new_version = get_version(filename)
      if (new_version > current_version):
        fileDict[obj] = filename
  return list(fileDict.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

Group the list by the prefix then use `max` to find the maximum version inside each group:

```
import os
from itertools import groupby
from functools import partial

keyfunc = lambda filename, idx: os.path.splitext(filename)[0].split("_")[idx]

sorted(filenames, key=partial(keyfunc, idx=0))
groups = groupby(filenames, key=partial(keyfunc, idx=0))

result = [
  max(items, key=partial(keyfunc, idx=1)) for key, items in groups
]

print(result)
```

Prints

```
['object1_245.ext', 'object2_010.ext', 'object3_142.ext']
```

Comment: Didn't you also post another solution yesterday? I had copied it, to understand how it worked, because I found it quite nice and simple. Would be great, if you could post it, too.

Comment: he did post another solution, when i posted mine he deleted it and posted this one, which is oddly very similar...